# Symfony 2 deployment 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, web-deployment, internal-server-error

I'm pretty new to symfony2 and to wed development as well. I have a trouble with deploying my symfony2 application to the server.

I'm getting `500 Internal Server Eror`

I have done everything what i want in my app and it perfectly works on localhost. Then I transferred my files on the server using ftp and created .htaccess file:

```
<Directory /web>
# enable the .htaccess rewrites
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

That's all what i changed in symfony2 app. Everything else is according to [Symfony 2 the book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html)

**About server**: it's just a dir carrying by apache and I don't have the access to the logs.

I can't understand the entrance point of application so I think that problem is in interaction between web/app.php and AppKernel.php.

Thank you!

Sorry for my bad english and newbie question.

Comment: Are you permissions set up correctly for the web server to be able to access everything? Have you tried the site using `app_dev.php` to see any debug info?

Comment: Every my request ends with internal server error 500. You can check it yourself if you want: http://442259.oeastate.web.hosting-test.net/

Comment: Have you set the permissions up correctly.. like I asked above

Comment: Yes, everything is ok  with permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else who is a total beginner in web dev on Symfony2. When you transfer your project to the remote server just make sure that your root directory is /web.